# how to list the messages of a certain number of users with admin SDK?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Is it possible that an administrator of domain acceded to the list of the messages of the users to be able to see the quantity of sent and received messages, together with the information of addressee and sender?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all  [users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_user) in the same domain, specific domain or account. Use this GET request 'GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users' and include the authorization described in  [Authorize requests](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing). You can retrieve information such as email, given name and address by using GET request, except for getting the quantity of messages received and sent. However, if you exceed the  [Google Apps email sending limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852), you may see an error message such as you have reached a limit for sending email and exceeded the maximum recipients.